# Unknown session related error in codeigniter after I enabled Memcached

Tags: php, memcached, codeigniter-3

Hi recently implemented memcached in my codeigniter application and migrated  from a DB based session to Memcached based session. Memcached is locally hosted.

Following is my Memcached related config.

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'memcached'; 
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'app_web_sessions';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 0;
$config['sess_save_path'] = 'localhost:11211'; 
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;
```

During one JSON call I'm getting the following error.

This API was working fine and if I hit the URL directly everything works fine.

```
<div style="border:1px solid #990000;padding-left:20px;margin:0 0 10px 0;">

<h4>A PHP Error was encountered</h4>

<p>Severity: Warning</p>
<p>Message:  ini_set(): A session is active. You cannot change the session module's ini settings at this time</p>
<p>Filename: Session/Session_driver.php</p>
<p>Line Number: 188</p>

<p style="margin-left:10px">
        File: 
 /var/www/html/application/libraries/REST_Controller.php<br />
        Line: 331<br />
        Function: __construct           </p>

        <p style="margin-left:10px">
        File: /var/www/html/index.php<br />
        Line: 324<br />
        Function: require_once          </p>
```

Also this error is not consistent. I'm stuck and looking around for answers on Stackoverflow did not help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Leaving this comment for others who might find this useful. I was not able to fix this so I rolled back to DB based session.